# How to remove duplicates from a list and take the largest out of those

Tags: python

I have the following list of dicts in python

```
[{'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1', 'Server3']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}]
```

I want ot remove duplicates from these and then take the largest value list out. In the above case my output would be

```
[{'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1', 'Server3']}]
```

To remove the duplicates I am trying.

```
result = [dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in result])]
```

It gives me the error `unhashable type: 'list'`. Any pointers in the right direction?

Comment: So, "largest" in your sense is the list with the most items?

Comment: What should happen if your list above also contained `{'JP': ['Server4']}`? Should `'Server4'` be present in the final result? Or are you _only_ looking for the  dict containing the longest 'JP' list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Easy to see how it works easy to modify :)

```
data = [{'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1', 'Server3']},
        {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']},
        {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}]

result = dict()
for dict_ in data:
    for key, values in dict_.iteritems():
        if len(values) > len(result.get(key, [])):
            result[key] = values
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm making assumptions about your dictionary here but if

```
x = [{'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1', 'Server3']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}, {'JP': ['Server2', 'Server1']}]

x.sort(key = lambda x:len(x['JP']))
```

Then

`x[-1]` will be what you want.

Update:
Borrowing an idea from Marco Bonelli's answer below, you don't have to actually sort the array. You can simply find the "largest" like so.

```
 max(x, key = lambda x:len(x['JP']))
```

Comment: Can I use x.keys() there just to avoid hardcoding 'JP'

Comment: `x.keys()` returns all the keys. Unless you state your problem more clearly, I'm afraid, all solutions are going to be insufficient.

Comment: No - that provides a `dict_keys` object, which can't be used as an index.  However, by wrapping it in a `for k in x[0].keys(): ...` you should be able to do it.  I'm sure there are better ways as well, but my brain hurts right now.  If the `JP` isn't a constant (but is defined elsewhere when the `dict`s are created, then grab it from wherever you define that key.